# How to replace a null value with a string with an EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this app with an EditText and when you click a button it sends the value to the second screen/activity. There is a hint in the EditText upon opening the app, but does that  count as not a null value? I currently have an if statement but it isn't working to replace the null value with "friend". 
How can i change the code to display "friend" when nothing is typed into the EditText?

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    if (message == null) {
        message = "Friend";
    }
    Log.d(TAG, message);


    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView.append(message);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

The method [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) returns the content of a TextView as a CharSequence which may be empty but not null. You can check if it's empty by calling `myTextView.getText().length == 0`.

If a TextVew is empty or filled only by a hint, the char sequence is just empty. Your second activity gets an empty string but never null. Check rather for an *empty string* than *null*.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on TextViews. I changed the if statement to test the length of the string and got it to work. Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras!= null) {
            textview.setText(extras.getString("message"));
        }else{
            textview.setText("Friend");
        }
```

i guess your problem is with the append (you dont have anything to join/add at the textview), first try with a setText(),later in your code, use a append if you want

Comment: After testing the first comment and finding it to be true your solution will leave with the same problem. Thanks for trying.